# Linearity condition not met in Excel Solver

Tags: excel, solver

I am trying to solve a flow problem in excel but the linearity condition is not met. I know it is because of the If function I am using but I don't know how else to express it. The used/unused cell takes the formula: =IF(Dec.Var=0,0,1).Here, Dec.Var = decision variables. I need to express used/unused column as 1 if corresponding decision variables != 0.
 I need this cell because other constraints are dependent on it such as cost = 1*unit cost, if used otherwise 0.

Comment: If you have a calculation like that, it is no longer a linear problem , you need to use one of the other solver engines.

Comment: The other approach is to just multiply your unit cost by the decision variable and that should then be linear , but it depends how you set up the rest of the model...